# cq5 design mode button missing

Tags: aem

We recently created new groups within our CMS to avoid users being added directly to folders. Following recommended best practices.

No default/main groups like 'everyone', 'administrators' etc where changed or removed from folders, only individuals in our marketing team. This has been working fine for the last few days,  but today, users as well as admins, no longer see the 'Design Mode' ruler icon on the sidekick. So are unable to edit pages.

I have a hunch this is ACL related suggested by the sites below:

http://blogs.adobe.com/dmcmahon/2012/03/09/cq-design-and-preview-mode-toolbar-not-visible/

http://dev.day.com/discussion-groups/content/lists/cq-google/2010-12/2010-12-07__day_communique__Design_of_component_bar_vanishes_in_design_view_Sourasree_Ghosh.html/2?q=design%20button

I've gone through and checked permissions to the /etc/designs folders and below but still no joy.

Would really appreciate your help on this one.
Any ideas?

Many Thanks
Warren

Comment: What version of CQ5 are you using? Have you tried clearing cookies? Also, have you tried using CRXDE Lite -> Tools to check the ACLs for one of the users [http://dev.day.com/docs/en/crx/current/developing/development_tools/developing_with_crxde_lite.html] - the 'Test Access Control' feature will give you more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran across this recently too.  Apparently when using the clientlib feature some thumbnails are not getting packaged properly.  This may have to do with using Eclipse.  The work-around was to [filter the assembly during the process-resource phase with Maven](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/examples/single/filtering-some-distribution-files.html).  This will ensure the thumbnails get copied properly as png files.